# Problems calculating means using tapply() in R

Tags: r, mean, tapply

I am trying to calculate means on a data.frame using the tapply() function.

Here is  my data frame.

```
   record            island      locale capture_type age_at_capt date_yyyy_mm_dd sex net mass (g) svl (mm)
6    1939 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   F          740      254
7    1940 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   F          815      270
8    1941 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   F          735      262
9    1942 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   M         1440      330
10   1943 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC       newcap       Adult      2018-03-25   M         1060      284
11   1944 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC       newcap       Adult      2018-03-25   M          810      275
12   1945 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-25   M         1375      310
13   1946 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-25   M         1395      325
14   1947 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-25   F          622      257
15   1948 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-25   M         1120      294
16   1949 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC       newcap       Adult      2018-03-25   F          690      247
18   1951 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-26   F          935      274
19   1952 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-27   M         2505      370
20   1953 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-27   F         1110      279
21   1954 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-27   F         1590      313
22   1955 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-27   M         1575      319
23   1956 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-27   M         1110      284
24   1957 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-27   M         2380      357
25   1958 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-27   M         2080      364
26   1959 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-27   F         1010      286
27   1960 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-27   M          830      259
28   1961 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-27   M         1850      348
29   1962 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-27   F         1250      296
30   1963 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-27   F         1075      282
31   1964 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   M         2240      362
32   1965 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   M         1775      338
33   1966 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   F         1420      300
34   1967 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   F         1010      263
35   1968 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   M         2090      372
36   1969 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-28   F         1440      304
37   1970 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   M          755      254
38   1971 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack       newcap       Adult      2018-03-28   F         1360      315
40   1973 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   M         2700      371
41   1974 Big Ambergris Cay Calico Jack        recap       Adult      2018-03-28   M         1820      331
42   1975 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-29   M         1450      326
43   1976 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-29   F          790      262
44   1977 Big Ambergris Cay         ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-29   F          605      246
```

Here is the same dataset outputted using dput()

```
structure(list(record = c(1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 
1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 
1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 
1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977), island = c("Big    Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", 
"Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay", "Big Ambergris Cay"
), locale = c("ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "ELC", 
"ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "ELC", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", 
"Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", 
"Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", 
"Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", 
"Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", "Calico Jack", 
"ELC", "ELC", "ELC"), capture_type = c("recap", "recap", "recap", 
"recap", "newcap", "newcap", "recap", "recap", "recap", "recap", 
"newcap", "recap", "recap", "newcap", "newcap", "recap", "newcap", 
"recap", "recap", "newcap", "newcap", "newcap", "recap", "recap", 
"recap", "recap", "recap", "recap", "recap", "newcap", "recap", 
"newcap", "recap", "recap", "recap", "recap", "recap"), age_at_capt =  c("Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult"), date_yyyy_mm_dd = c("2018-03-24", "2018-03-24", "2018-03-24", 
"2018-03-24", "2018-03-25", "2018-03-25", "2018-03-25", "2018-03-25", 
"2018-03-25", "2018-03-25", "2018-03-25", "2018-03-26", "2018-03-27", 
"2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", 
"2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-27", 
"2018-03-27", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", 
"2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-28", 
"2018-03-28", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-29"), sex = c("F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"), `net mass (g)` = c(740, 
815, 735, 1440, 1060, 810, 1375, 1395, 622, 1120, 690, 935, 2505, 
1110, 1590, 1575, 1110, 2380, 2080, 1010, 830, 1850, 1250, 1075, 
2240, 1775, 1420, 1010, 2090, 1440, 755, 1360, 2700, 1820, 1450, 
790, 605), `svl (mm)` = c(254, 270, 262, 330, 284, 275, 310, 
325, 257, 294, 247, 274, 370, 279, 313, 319, 284, 357, 364, 286, 
259, 348, 296, 282, 362, 338, 300, 263, 372, 304, 254, 315, 371, 
331, 326, 262, 246)), row.names = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is to calculate the mean for the 'net mass (g)' variable according to two variables with 2 factor-levels each : 1)'locale', with levels "ELC" and "Calico Jack"; 2) 'sex', with levels "M" and "F". In other words, I would expect to end up with 4 mean values. Here is the tapply() function that I am using (and that I have successfully used on other database but this one).

```
MeanMass.2018 <- tapply(Records.2018.BA.ad$`net mass (g)`, 
                    INDEX = Records.2018.BA.ad$locale : Records.2018.BA.ad$sex, 
                    FUN   = mean)
```

Unfortunately I do not get the mean values. Instead this nasty error message comes up, and I am really frustrated because I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with this data set.

```
Error in Records.2018.BA.ad$locale:Records.2018.BA.ad$sex : 
 NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Records.2018.BA.ad$locale:Records.2018.BA.ad$sex :
 numerical expression has 37 elements: only the first used
2: In Records.2018.BA.ad$locale:Records.2018.BA.ad$sex :
 numerical expression has 37 elements: only the first used
3: In tapply(Records.2018.BA.ad$`net mass (g)`, INDEX =     Records.2018.BA.ad$locale:Records.2018.BA.ad$sex,  :
 NAs introduced by coercion
4: In tapply(Records.2018.BA.ad$`net mass (g)`, INDEX =    Records.2018.BA.ad$locale:Records.2018.BA.ad$sex,  :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `Records.2018.BA.ad$locale : Records.2018.BA.ad$sex` is not correct syntax. For `tapply`, use `with(Records.2018.BA.ad, tapply('net mass (g)',  list(locale,  sex), mean))`

Comment: Even if I try with your suggestion I still don't get it to work. I think there is something weird in the data.frame cause the error is now:   `Error in tapply("net mass (g)", list(locale, sex), mean) :`
  `arguments must have same length`

Comment: Cinghio ; please note i used a single apostrophe ( ' ) around  net mass, to allow me to highlight it in the comment. Try it using the backtick ( `) as you did in your question.

Comment: Backticks or single quotes around net mass should both work.

Comment: eg : with(dat, tapply((backtick)net mass (g)(backtick), list(locale, sex), mean)) works. But having names like this is a pain. I'd advise you change them. one quick way is `names(dat) = make.names(names(dat))`, and then `with(dat, tapply(net.mass..g., list(locale, sex), mean))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified your sample dataframe, but I think with my last line, the aggregate() function, will get you where you want:

```
 df <- read.table(text = "
record island locale capture_type age_at_capt date_yyyy_mm_dd sex netmass svl 
1939 BigAmbergrisCay    ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   F          740      254
1940 BigAmbergrisCay    ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   F          815      270
1941 BigAmbergrisCay    ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   F          735      262
1942 BigAmbergrisCay    ELC        recap       Adult      2018-03-24   M         1440      330
1943 BigAmbergrisCay    ELC       newcap       Adult      2018-03-25   M         1060      284
1944 BigAmbergrisCay    ELC       newcap       Adult      2018-03-25   M          810      275
", header = T)

df <- rbind(df, df)

df$locale <- as.character(df$locale)
df$locale[7:12] <- "other locale"
df$netmass[7:12] <- seq(1500,2000,100)


aggregate(netmass ~ locale + sex, df, mean)


       locale sex   netmass
1         ELC   F  763.3333
2 otherlocale   F 1600.0000
3         ELC   M 1103.3333
4 otherlocale   M 1900.0000
```

With tapply:

```
tapply(df$netmass, list(df$locale, df$sex), mean)
```

OR

```
with(df, tapply(netmass, list(locale, sex), mean))
```

Both give:

```
                 F        M
ELC           763.3333 1103.333
other locale 1600.0000 1900.000
```

Comment: The aggregate() function is one way to go about it and it definitely gets the job done. Still, I am struggling to understand why I get the error message and why the the other method is not working.

Comment: On my slight modification of your sample data the tapply function does work as well. I have updated my answer. Please dput() your (sample) data if you cannot get it to work on your data.

Comment: I think there is something off with my data frame, but I am not yet quite sure what.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the whole dataset. Still can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: I see. It would be easier to dput(yourdata) because then we don't need additional code to read your data. At a glimpse I'd suggest to get rid of the brackets and spaces in your column names and try it again.

Comment: done. (or at least I think I am done, cause I never used dput() before). I thought about the names, haven't tried it yet. If that is the actual issue I will be really upset. In the meantime, thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the dput. I assigned it to df, and both my tapply commands work fine: 

`tapply(df$'net mass (g)', list(df$locale, df$sex), mean)`
OR 
`with(df, tapply('net mass (g)', list(locale, sex), mean))`

Comment: You are right, It does work, and really the only thing I could see different is the name of those two variables. Although it is very strange because if I try and manually change using colnames() on the original dataset it still won't work. Go figure....Thanks again.